# Using the T5 model with huggingface's mask-fill pipeline

Tags: neural-network, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the T5 model with hugging face's mask-fill pipeline?  The below is how you can do it using the default model but i can't seem to figure out how to do is using the T5 model specifically?

```
from transformers import pipeline
nlp_fill = pipeline('fill-mask')
nlp_fill('Hugging Face is a French company based in ' + nlp_fill.tokenizer.mask_token)
```

Trying this for example raises the error "TypeError: must be str, not NoneType" because nlp_fill.tokenizer.mask_token is None.

```
nlp_fill = pipeline('fill-mask',model="t5-base", tokenizer="t5-base")
nlp_fill('Hugging Face is a French company based in ' + nlp_fill.tokenizer.mask_token)
```